# React Kiosk app on Google Chrome crashes on multi touch input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, kiosk

We have a Kiosk App (written in React) and it is working on ~800 devices. All of the devices are Windows devices and for some of them (about 5%), when a user without tech literacy uses more than one finger (lets say he tries to input his customer number but with using three fingers instead of one) the app crashes after a point (Google Chrome is not responding error).

I do not know why, but when I tried to debug the app on live environment using localhost:9222 as my Chrome DevTools output, I could raise some errors while scrolling and clicking the app, but I cannot create the user input remotely, because I am using a mouse, not a touch screen. And I cannot debug on the devices.

Does anybody have an idea on what is wrong? And how can I stop the crashes?

What I tried to do so far;

- Tried to enable Crash Logs, couldn't make it log to a file so I can inspect it, nothing gets logged
- Tried to create a chrome console log file, but nothing is shown here too
- Tried to change screen input type from touch to mouse click, didn't fix it
- Tried to use Chrome Command Line Switches such as disable-pinch and enable-crash-reporter but none of them seem to give me any info or fix the problem

Any tips?

Comment: Still waiting for help!